# Failing to Capture Child Element Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iteration

I have a column of 3 draggable items that can be placed into two droppable areas. After each drop, I need to tally up the total number of child DIV elements contained within each droppable area. I'm having difficulty with this tally. However, I am unable to get the array length of child elements as seen in the snippet below.

```
var childrenTotal = 0;
$("div.answer").each(function () {
     childrenTotal = $(this).children('div').length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mQKzr/2/

Comment: your fiddle changes the scope of childrenTotal, but you also need to do `childrenTotal += $(this).children('div').length` if you want to get them all, otherwise all it's doing is returning the children in the final one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var childrenTotal = $(this).children('div').length;
```

To:

```
childrenTotal += $(this).children('div').length;
```

Comment: Good eyes. All that complex coding and I fail on the basics. That always happens.